# How to get Light Vector for diffuse term

Tags: opengl, 3d

Given the light position (x,y,z) and the position of the pixel (x,y,z) how would one find the light vector, L, for the diffuse term of the local illumination equation? This is for the phong illumination model.

Comment: Define "position of the pixel"? Are the "pixel" position and the light position in the same space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equation to find Light Direction Vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521054/equation-to-find-light-direction-vector) Don't ask the same question again 5 hours later.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do a vector subtraction? Make sure your vectors are in the same coordianate system, then do `vec3 L = lightPos - pixelPos`.

Assuming both your vectors were in eye coordinates, you would typically do

```
float diffuseLight = I_d * k_d * max(L * vec(0,0,1), 0)
```

Afterward to get the contribution from the light.

You should give a little more context to you question, it's not very easy to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Both vectors must be in the same coordinate system.

For point light, the position of the light is finite (`w != 0`) and the light vector is

```
vec4 L = normalize (light - point);
```

For directional light, the position of the light is infinite (`w == 0`) and the light vector is the position of the light itself

```
vec4 L = light;
```